# Dynamically configuring the outputPath in angular.json build directory in maven project

Tags: angular, maven

I have created a maven angular project which has artifact   `<artifactId>student-ui</artifactId>` with version `<version>2023.1-angular-SNAPSHOT</version>`
And it will create a war like this `student-ui-2023.1-angular-SNAPSHOT`.
Right now, i have configured the angular.json with

```
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "target/student-ui-2023.1-angular-SNAPSHOT",
```

but whenever we are doing release, the versioning of the pom will get changes(from 2023.1-angular-SNAPSHOT to 2023.2-angular-SNAPSHOT), Is it possible to configure the angular.josn outputPath property dynamically in sync with the maven pom versioning. Appreciate any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in the war module:

```
<build>
    <finalName>student-ui-angular</finalName>
    ...
</build>
```

This will remove version from the target path and generated war file.

As alternative you can give a try to *maven-resource-plugin* [filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html):

```
<project>
    ...
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
    ...
</project>
```

an inject whatever property you like.

Comment: Hi ursa,I don't want to remove the versioning, i want to maintain the version number and use it in the angular.json? is it possible to read the version number in angular.json file

Comment: I don't know your project structure, however you definitely can customise maven-resource-plugin filtering in the way `"target/student-ui-${project.version}"` will be replaced in `angular.json` with actual maven project version